# Executing asyncio method from a synchronous method / blocking until complete in Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I really don't want to update my large code base such that `async` and `await` are used in every method dependent on an asynchronous function or method. But this seems impossible.

From what I can tell, there is no convenient way to

1. Define two asynchronous functions
2. Collect them and wait on them
3. Block any further application logic until step 2 is complete
4. Never mention async or await again in any such application logic downstream of 1 and 2.

Is this possible?

If so, how can I call asynchronous methods from a method that is not proceeded by the async keyword? (ex in 3.) Because if this is not possible, then async / await will spread like a virus through all my code.

```py
import asyncio 
class Application:

   def __init__(self, A, B):
      self.A = A
      self.B = B 

   async def pull(self, stuff):
      result = aws.get_stuff(stuff) 
      return await result 
   
   def applicationLogic(self):
      pass 

   async def aws_wrapper(self):
      self.aPull = self.pull(self.A)
      self.bPull = self.pull(self.B)
      tasks = [self.aPull, self.bPull]
      return await asyncio.wait(tasks)

   def aws_async_executor(self):
      loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
      loop.run_until_complete(self.aws_wrapper())
      self.applicationLogic()
```

Error: "errorMessage": "An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required",

Comment: *Because if this is not possible, then async / await will spread like a virus through all my code.* yes, see https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/

Comment: Can you please show the error traceback? Currently it's unclear where the error message is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually, if you have a single async function, you juts have to instantiate an asyncio loop, by calling `loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()`, and then call `loop.run_until_complete()`  passing your async function.

Nothing really special. The same call can then be used if you have other async functions you want to run synchronously.

Comment: I edited prompt as I understood your recommendation. Is this what you had in mind?